# Spring Security- How to specify filter processing url in CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to secure my Spring Rest API with token here is my custom filter

```
public class CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);

    public CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(defaultFilterProcessesUrl));
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoOpAuthenticationManager());
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    }


    public final String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "X-CustomToken"; 

    @Override 
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
        logger.info("token found:"+token);
        AbstractAuthenticationToken userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken(token);
        if(userAuthenticationToken == null || userAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal().equals("guest")) throw new AuthenticationServiceException(MessageFormat.format("Error | {0}", "Bad Token"));
        return userAuthenticationToken;
    }


    /**
     * authenticate the user based on token
     * @return
     */
    private AbstractAuthenticationToken authUserByToken(String token) {
        if(token==null) {
            return null;
        }
        AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken = new MyToken(token);
        try {
            return authToken;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Authenticate user by token error: ", e);
        }
        return authToken;
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }

}
```

and here is how I configured it

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    protected AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter getFilter() {
        return new CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter("/api/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(getFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

If you look at the getFilter(), I have passed "/api/*" as a filter processing url, but I want to configure these urls with HttpSecurity object, some thing as follows

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/rome").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin", "/api/newUser").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/api/db").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
```

Problem I see is that, the Custom filter requires a String as "filter processing url" but I do not want specify anything. That information should be passed by configuring `HttpSecurity` object through `antMatchers` etc.

**Is it really possible? if yes how can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 0):

I used `OncePerRequestFilter`.

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    // private RequestMatcher requestMatcher;
    private List<RequestMatcher> includedPathMatchers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<RequestMatcher> excludedPathMatchers = new ArrayList<>();

    // implement getters and setters
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // your filter implementation and security logics
    }

}
```

You can treat this class as a normal bean (use `@Autowired` and so on). Then you just need do register it in your context and inject it in the security chain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how to populate both includedPathMatchers and excludedPathMatchers? How and where this values are available?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46890422/2181576) will be useful to you. It says to use setter setFilterProcessingURL() available in AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter