# Set custom login url in Spring Security UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter JWT authentication

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt, auth0

I'm following [this auth0's tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) to secure my application using JWT.

I've ended up with the following WebSecurity configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .and().cors()
                .and().csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, REGISTER_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // This disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

}
```

and the following JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            ApplicationUser credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            credentials.getUsername(),
                            credentials.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>()
                    )
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();
        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

At the moment, the app accepts POST requests on the `/login` URL. I wonder how to change the URL to, let's say, `/api/auth/login`. Is there any way to inject the URL string into the authentication filter or to set it somehow in the security config?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are extending [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) which itself extends 
[org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html). In this last class, there is a setter called `setFilterProcessesUrl` which is intended to do just this:

> **setFilterProcessesUrl**
>
> public void ***setFilterProcessesUrl***(String filterProcessesUrl)
>
> Sets the URL that determines if authentication is required
>
> Parameters: filterProcessesUrl

[This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#setFilterProcessesUrl-java.lang.String-) is the link to that javadoc section

So in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you could do just like this:

```
@Bean
public JWTAuthenticationFilter getJWTAuthenticationFilter() {
    final JWTAuthenticationFilter filter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/auth/login");
    return filter;
}
```

And then in your `configure` method in the same class just reference it instead of creating new instance:

```
.addFilter(getJWTAuthenticationFilter())
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked as a charm! There's a small oversight in your answer though, you've confused JWTAuthorizationFilter with JWTAuthenticationFilter. But still, it works perfectly.

Comment: can we do this same case with oauth2 own resource server in springboot ?

Comment: @YasirShabbirChoudhary I think so, but not sure at all. You could give it a try and in case it does not work, you could post a question and I will check it

Comment: @jilumietu - Thank you for this answer. I have one question for you. Is it possible to make Spring security allow other methods like DELETE or PUT to the filterprocessesUrl in this way?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran, I´ve not tested it but it should. Method `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(String filterProcessesUrl)` internally calls `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(filterProcessesUrl));`. The constructor `AntPathRequestMatcher(String filterProcessesUrl)` intilializes `HttpMethod httpMethod` property to null, which makes the method `public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request)` don't evaluate the incoming `HttpServletRequest`'s method. So according to this, other methods should definitely work

Comment: @jlumietu - sounds great. let me give it a try then

Answer (score 3):

A little improvement could be to just create your filter with custom process url and use it without create a bean that I think you don't need anywhere else than here.

```
JWTAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/mobile/login");
....
.and()
.addFilter(authenticationFilter)
.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
```