# JWT login wont work on deployed spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm following this [JWT tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/) to secure my application.

I've ended up with the following WebSecurity configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private MyPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfiguration(MyUserDetailsService userService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = new MyPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                //SIGN_UP_URL = "/login";
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.logout().permitAll();
        http.logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .addLogoutHandler(new SecurityContextLogoutHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .clearAuthentication(true));

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

        return source;
    }
```

and the following JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        
        //SIGN_UP_URL= "/login"
        setFilterProcessesUrl(MySettings.SIGN_UP_URL); 
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException {
        String token;
        token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + MySettings.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(Algorithm.HMAC512(MySettings.SECRET.getBytes()));

        String body = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername() + " " + token;

        res.getWriter().write(body);
        res.getWriter().flush();
    }
```

---

**Problem**

At the moment, the app accepts GET requests on the /login URL when starting the app on my computer/localhost. I use postman and Im able to login and receive the token.

When I deploy the application to the server, the /login automatically replies with 403 forbidden.

The databases are equal.

What am I doing wrong?

**References**

[Set custom login url in Spring Security UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter JWT authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889350/set-custom-login-url-in-spring-security-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-jwt)

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/

Comment: that tutorial is 2 years old and is not how you implement the handling of JWTs in spring security. Please check the official spring security documentation chapter on JWTs on how to properly implement the handling using the JWTFilter that already exists in spring security.

Comment: You mean a tutorial like this? https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-security-jwt-authentication-tutorial Or This? https://blog.iamprafful.com/spring-boot-rest-api-authentication-best-practices-using-jwt-2022

Comment: spring security official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html you should ALWAYS start with reading the official documentation for something. Dont use tutorials

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

above your login Api in your controller